# How to fix "Client Request Interrupted" error in Heroku (with a rails app)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

1. I deployed my rails app on Heroku.
2. When I try to create a new profile, my app crashes. My logs display a Client Request Interrupted error. You can see my logs below.
3. I searched this error on heroku dev center: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/662

On this page (https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/662):

It said : "This error will be logged if the client socket was closed either in the middle of the request or before a response could be returned."

Then

"This error condition caused an H18 to be logged and the sock field could be used to differentiate between what are now H18 and H27 errors. "

H18 - Server Request Interrupted

The backend socket, belonging to your app’s web process was closed before the backend returned an HTTP response.

```
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905345+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma)
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905399+00:00 app[web.1]: SignalException: SIGTERM
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905401+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:398:in `block in setup_signals'
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905406+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/single.rb:115:in `join'
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905407+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/single.rb:115:in `run'
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905409+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:184:in `run'
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905410+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:78:in `run'
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905412+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905414+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2019-02-05T15:53:19.905415+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
2019-02-05T21:33:39.526627+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2019-02-05T21:33:53.579585+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2019-02-05T21:33:53.579631+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2019-02-05T21:33:53.579632+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2019-02-05T21:33:53.579634+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2019-02-05T21:34:00.063370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-05T21:33:59.640588+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:11397
2019-02-05T21:33:59.642173+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2019-02-05T21:34:02.204235+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/" host=agora-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=9d994b8b-eff4-4088-b2be-a42b14fec708 fwd="209.17.96.226" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=119ms status=499 bytes= protocol=https
```

The important part to notice is the sock=client which means that the request was interrupted at the request of the client:

```
2019-02-05T21:34:02.204235+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/" host=agora-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=9d994b8b-eff4-4088-b2be-a42b14fec708 fwd="209.17.96.226" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=119ms status=499 bytes= protocol=https
```

I didn't understand either Heroku dev center explanations nor previous Stack Overflow questions.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1438, looks like a similar error log.